# Rasa NLU Trainer-How to fix "Can't find training file" error?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, rasa-nlu

I am creating a weather bot using `RASA` stack.I am trying to access the `NLU Trainer GUI` but am getting an error.
It says that it can't find a training file even though I have created a JSON file.It is stored in - `Desktop/weather_bot/data`.I have also successfully installed the nlu trainer using

`sudo npm i -g rasa-nlu-trainer`

But when i try to access the GUI using rasa-nlu-trainer , I get the following error

```
Desktop/weather_bot/data/data.json
searching for the training examples...
(node:31971) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Can't find training file, please try to specify it with the --source option
    at checkDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rasa-nlu-trainer/server.js:98:15)
    at readData.then.catch.then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rasa-nlu-trainer/server.js:128:11)
    at <anonymous>
(node:31971) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:31971) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

\

Answer (score 2):

Mostly this error is thrown because of this lines of code `if(!json.rasa_nlu_data){ return reject("....") }` in server.js, and to resolve this, try to include `{"rasa_nlu_data": {` as your first lines of code in your data.json file or your training data file, hope this will resolve your issue,

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. I included {"rasa_nlu_data": { on the first lines of code in my data.json file. But I discovered my JSON file was a bit mistake. I put a comma in the last JSON data. So check whether your JSON file is okay or not. I think it should work if it's oka.

Answer (score 0):

This command should work.

`rasa-nlu-trainer --source Desktop/weather_bot/data/data.json`